# Wordpress - Mostrar el subtitulo (campo personalizado) en página de inicio

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Hola y gracias por vuestra atención.
En mi página de wordpress ([www.escoladeferrado.es](http://www.escoladeferrado.es)) he creado un campo personalizado "Subtitulo" y me funciona perfectamente en los post individuales, pero no consigo que me aparezca en la página de incio. Os dejo el código que coloqué en "functions.php", y a ver si se os ocurre algo. Uso el tema Hueman. Gracias de antemano.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', function () {
if (is_singular()):
    $subtitulo = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Subtitulo', true);
    if ( $subtitulo ):
    ?>
    <script>
        (function( $ ) {
            let str = '<span class="dcms-subtitle">';
            str += '<?= $subtitulo ?>';
            str += '</span>';
            $(str).insertBefore('.entry-title');
        })( jQuery );
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
endif;
} );
```

Comment: [`is_singular()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/) es para posts individuales, para la página del inicio podes usar `is_page()`, `is_home()` o [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) según cómo tengas configurado qué mostrar en el raíz ( lo agregas a la condición con un  `||`  )

Comment: @aloMalbarez tiene razon, is_singular es para el single.php por lo que si quieres usarlo en paginas diferentes dentro de grupos tendras que cambiar tu condición por is_page(), is_home(), etc. Según necesites.

Comment: dado q en el home hay varios posts el javascript va a encontrar el primero ( o la página seteada como frontpage ) fijate de editar el template part que imprime el título de los [single posts](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/hueman/3.7.12/parts/single-heading.php), si estas editando un child-theme copia el archivo `parts/single-heading.php` y lo editas en el child theme

Comment: Gracias por vuestra ayuda. Efectivamente si cambio el "is_singular" por "is_home", me aparece e subtitulo, pero le pone EL MISMO SUBTITULO a todos los post, tengan o no tengan ese campo cubierto.
He eliminado el código del functions_php y lo he puesto en single_heading.php, pero entonces no me aparece el subtitulo en ningún lado. Me imagino quje es mi torpeza y desconocimiento, pero muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda y vuestro tiempo.